# How to use `sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric` to compute distances

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using an `sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric` to construct a `BallTree`.  However, I then need to use that distance metric for further computations.  How does one use an `sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric` to compute distances?  For example, if `x = np.array([1,2])` and `y = np.array([4,6])`:

```
>>> sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.get_metric("euclidean").compute_distances(x,y)
... 5
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?  [The docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.html) only seem to suggest a `pairwise` method which computes all of the pairwise distances, which I do not need.  Ideally, `x` and `y` might be arrays of points, and `compute_distances` would broadcast along the -1 axis.